# API call issue inside docker container

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am facing the following error message when I try to make an api call inside a docker container.

> HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:21000)

Both the front-end and the api are on the same machine.

here's the dockerfile for the front-end

````
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerBasicClientServe2/DockerBasicClientServe2.csproj", "DockerBasicClientServe2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerBasicClientServe2/DockerBasicClientServe2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerBasicClientServe2"
RUN dotnet build "DockerBasicClientServe2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerBasicClientServe2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerBasicClientServe2.dll"]  ```
````

Here's the dockerfile for the api

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyRestApi/MyRestApi.csproj", "MyRestApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyRestApi/MyRestApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyRestApi"
RUN dotnet build "MyRestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyRestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyRestApi.dll"]
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockerbasicclientserve2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerbasicclientserve2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerBasicClientServe2\Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "5200:80"
     - "5201:443"

  myrestapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myrestapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyRestApi\Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "21000:80"
```

And here's the code I am using to make the call:

```cs
  public async Task<IActionResult> Weather()
        {
            var weatherForeCastResponse = await this._client.GetAsync("http://localhost:21000/WeatherForecast");
            var temp = await weatherForeCastResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var weatherForeCast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>(temp);

            return View(weatherForeCast);
        }
```

Note:  If I paste this url directly in the browser, it works:  `http://localhost:21000/WeatherForecast`.

Comment: `http://myrestapi:21000/WeatherForecast` from another container of the same Docker network.

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε, can you please elaborate? I am pretty new at docker.  An example will also be very helpful

Comment: Thanks for you reply @β.εηοιτ.βε. It turned out to be solution to my problem. It was so concise that I did not get it at first.  I had to change it just a little bit to make it work. Like this:  http://myrestapi:80/WeatherForecast

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @β.εηοιτ.βε's comment: using `localhost` in the front-end container won't reach out to the endpoint for the api mapped on the docker host. However as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) you can connect using `<servicename>:<containerport>`.

Bonus Note: you don't even need to map a Host port for the back-end service (you can if you want). Your front-end service is only relying on exposing the container port.